# How to get value from database into int java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, swing

I created a program where I need to parse and value from database into integer and put it to JLabel, the problem is that showed value is always 0, but when I check statement in database it shows the right value. 
code:

```
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("database....");
    stat = conn.createStatement();
    result = stat.executeQuery("statement...(works fine) ");
    integerx =  ((Number) result.getObject(1)).intValue();  

    result.close();
    stat.close();
}catch (Exception e){

}
label.setText("the value is : " + integerx );
```

How can I get the value from database? The data is limited to show 1 column and 1 row.

Comment: Did you already step through the code? Because your empty exception handler acts like a black hole for errors, so if anything goes wrong you'll never know.

Comment: Hey @fvu , the code works fine with empty exceptions, got a bunch of them in my code! :)

Comment: Sooner or later you will profoundly regret that silly choice. And `}catch (Exception e){` aka the universal flycatcher is an almost equally stupid idea.

Comment: Thanks, ill keep it in mind and try to rework on it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
integerx = result.getInt(1); // if the data exist on the first column
```

Comment: thanks for answer @amine, despite attempts it still gives value of 0

Comment: is the querry result unique ? ( contains where clause )